# Omniture SiteCatalist searches vs. visits

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are making updates to our site analytics dashboard.  For the search section should we look at Searches or Visits or both?  What are the differences between Searches and Visits metrics in Omniture?

Answer (score 0):

Searches are identical to Instances. [This article](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/home/index.html#kb-comparing-visits-and-instances) has the exact answers you're looking for.

**Searches:** The number of times a search was performed.

**Visits:** The number of sessions within a given time period where a search was performed.

Answer (score 0):

Visits: The number of sessions within a given time period. A visit is defined as a sequence of consecutive page views without a 30-minute break, or continuous activity for 12 hours. They most commonly consist of multiple image requests, however visitors that bounce can consist of a single page view.

Instances/Search: The number of times a variable was defined. Each time Adobe Analytics sees a value within a variable, instances increment by one in that respective report.